# rastervision training issue using learner

Tags: pytorch, raster, torchvision, pytorch-lightning, geotiff

i am using the indirect method. now i am having shape issue. even though my shape of input data (train/val/test :img/lbl) are tensor 3d, the learner function is issuing an error. below is the configuration, shape of data and the error details.

```
train_image_uri = '/home/nicku/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ma_dataset/png/train'
train_label_uri = '/home/nicku/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ma_dataset/png/train_labels'
val_image_uri = '/home/nicku/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ma_dataset/png/val'
val_label_uri = '/home/nicku/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/ma_dataset/png/val_labels'

data_augmentation_transform = A.Compose([
A.Flip(),
A.ShiftScaleRotate(),
A.OneOf([
A.HueSaturationValue(hue_shift_limit=10),
A.RGBShift(),
A.ToGray(),
A.ToSepia(),
A.RandomBrightness(),
A.RandomGamma(),
]),
A.CoarseDropout(max_height=32, max_width=32, max_holes=5)
])

train_ds = SemanticSegmentationImageDataset(
img_dir=train_image_uri,
label_dir=train_label_uri,
transform=data_augmentation_transform
)
val_ds = SemanticSegmentationImageDataset(
img_dir=val_image_uri,
label_dir=val_label_uri,
transform= A.Resize(256, 256)
)
out: x shape for train_ds torch.Size([3, 1500, 1500])
out: y shape for train_ds torch.Size([1500, 1500, 3])
out: x shape of train_ds after data_augmentation_transform (1500, 1500, 3)
out: x shape for val_ds torch.Size([3, 256, 256])
out: y shape for val_ds torch.Size([256, 256, 3])
out: x shape of val_ds after data_augmentation_transform (256, 256, 3)

data_cfg = SemanticSegmentationGeoDataConfig(
class_names=class_config.names,
class_colors=class_config.colors,
num_workers=4, # increase to use multi-processing
)

solver_cfg = SolverConfig(
batch_sz=1,
test_batch_sz=1,
lr=1e-4,
class_loss_weights=[0.5, 0.5], # [1., 10.],
)

model = SemanticSegmentationModelConfig(backbone=Backbone.resnet50)
learner_cfg = SemanticSegmentationLearnerConfig(data=data_cfg, solver=solver_cfg, model=model)

learner = SemanticSegmentationLearner(
cfg=learner_cfg,
output_dir=learner_dir,
train_ds=train_ds,
valid_ds=val_ds,
)
learner.train(epochs=3)
error 1: ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, 256, 1, 1])
```

But, when i change batch_sz to 2, i get:

```
error 2: RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [2, 1500, 1500, 3]
```

when i set batch_sz as 3 or above, i get:

```
error 3: RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 830.00 MiB (GPU 0; 23.70 GiB total capacity; 20.99 GiB already allocated; 479.44 MiB free; 21.31 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation. See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

i am using rtx 3070.
the size of my images and labels are 1500*1500 (as i guess rv resize or data augmentation resize or maybe we dont need to resize)

before i was having geotiff issue, that issue is resolved and now i am having shape issue